# User processes continue to run after logout

Tags: kde, logout, .profile

I have put the following code in my `.profile`

```
ps cax | grep jackd > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Jack is aready running."
fi

if [ "$SESSION_TYPE" != "remote/ssh" ] && [ "$DISPLAY" ]; then
    ps cax | grep jackd > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Jack is aready running."
    else
        jackd --sync -P80 -p128 -dalsa -dhw:UA25 -r48000 -p64 -n3 -Xraw &
        jack_wait -w
        alsaj &
        ~/deployed/syzmo/x86_64-GNU%2fLinux/syzmo_client_studio &
    fi
fi
```

When I logout from KDE and log in on tty1, I see the message "Jack is already running". When listing processes, I see that I have started it, so I conclude that jack never stopped. How could that be?

Here is what I see from ps -u when logging in from tty1:

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2053 ?        00:32:39 jackd
 2079 ?        00:00:00 alsaj
 2082 ?        00:11:00 alsa_in
10265 tty1     00:00:00 bash
10295 tty1     00:00:00 ps
```

Why do I still see `jackd` and `alsa_in` among running processes?

#### Follow-up:

Since the processes does not die when logging out, there has to be a corresponding log-out script that does not run as root. Is there a way of cleaning up any side-effects caused by `.profile`?

Answer (score 0):

It is still running because you didn't stop it.  You shouldn't be starting daemons like this in your .profile.  A normally installed jackd package will set itself up to be automatically started and stopped at the appropriate times via upstart.

Comment: So I can continue to run processes without actually be logged in? I added these commands since I wanted more explicit control over the command line. Are you sure `jackd` is started by upstart. Jackd is a user process. It is typically started by QjackCtl or another fronted, and why would those use the `init` daemon.